# VBA Code to select 1st plank row in column H, then select blank columns to the right

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I am trying to write a copy/paste VBA code for Excel to pull data from a source sheet and paste it in a different format in a destination sheet. I am very new to this so I really don't know what I am doing but I am giving it a go as I really want to learn.

In the end, I want to have a loop which copies data out of a sheet and pastes it in a single row in a new workbook. The source sheet has many columns where the desired values are "paired" within the same column in two diff rows (eg. C72 and C73), with many pairs spread across 32 columns with gaps (eg. first pair=C72,C73, next pair=F72,F73 and so on). When pasting I want the paired values to be transposed so that all the data is in a single row.

To keep this simple, I am breaking it into parts, with the current issue being a code that will select the next blank cell to the right in the destination sheet to copy the paired values into. I will then incorporate this into a loop (not sure how yet) to go back and forth until all the data has been copied out.

I have found a lot of code referring to the next blank row:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        lastrow = 1
    End If
End With
```

But I am unsure if this can be applied to columns or how one would modify it if it can.

Comment: It might be helpful to see sample data and the expected result. You can post screen caps on https://imgur.com/ and link to them here

Comment: This is a good point, but is there no way to upload sample workbooks?

Comment: Most people will not download files from unknown sources. Also, once the link to the workbook is gone, your question loses its usefulness to future visitors